# .htaccess redirect for a specific folder files from non-www to www

Tags: wordpress, redirect

The website travoline.com is hosted in wordpress - which has a .htaccess file which redirects non-www to www. Whereas I have few inside pages which is created in .html in a separate folder outside wordpress i.e. http://www.travoline.com/hotels/intl/united-kingdom/london.html  - How do I redirect the above html url from non-www to www (Rewrite Engine on). Where should I add .htacess to use this redirection. (should I add it in the hotels folder or in the intl folder.)

Answer (score 0):

The following in the .htaccess at the root of www.travoline.com should work for any URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^travoline.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.travoline.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The RewriteCond checks that the URL is for travoline.com (not www.travoline.com).

If so, the it redirects the connectioni to http://www.travoline.com/ with the rest of the path appended.

You should read up on mod_rewrite (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html).